# What is the official word that refers to both bride and groom?

Tags: single-word-requests

Instead of saying, e.g. "Before the wedding, I spoke to the bride and groom", is there a single word meaning, "those to be married"?

I thought of "postulants", e.g. "Before the wedding, I spoke to the postulants."

From this  dictionary however postulant does not have the right meaning.

> Definition of postulant 1: a person admitted to a religious order as a
> probationary candidate for membership 2: a person on probation before
> being admitted as a candidate for holy orders in the Episcopal Church.
> [[M-W]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/postulant)

**Question**

Is there such a single word or must you always refer separately to "the bride and groom"?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

**'The espoused'** refers to both persons who are engaged to be married.

[Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/64428?rskey=asoS46&result=1#eid) :

> **espouse**

> *1946 O. F. Grazebrook Nicanor of Athens xi. 159 Take your pleasure now, but know that **I have espoused you** to Chrysilla..and y**ou will marry her***.

> (a) transitive. To give in marriage; to marry (a person to another, esp. a woman to a man; formerly also with †with); to arrange for (a person, esp. a woman, or a couple) to be married; to betroth.

(My additional note : Using the past participle with an article "the espoused" denotes those who are engaged and are pursuing the activity of espousal.)

> Betrothal (also called **espousal**) is a formal state of engagement to be married.

> [Wikipedia - Engagement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engagement)

Comment: "The Betrothed" is probably a good word.  It's a good book too!

Comment: Both are unusual but I think the betrothed more likely to recognized by a modern reader.

Answer (score 2):

There is no single word that is really commonly used. Some might be accurate, but they are so uncommon as to sound strange to some people.

I would say the most accessible single word is [**betrothed**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/betrothed):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> *adjective*
> : engaged to be married a betrothed couple
> // … clasped hands, signifying the bond between *betrothed* men and women …
> — Mary Feilden
> // For three years she and Emilio Estevez were an item and were even *betrothed* for a time.
> — *People Weekly*
>
> *noun*
> : the person to whom someone is engaged to be married
> // … she put on her grey silk gown and her cherry coloured ribbon with as much care as if she had been herself the *betrothed*.
> — George Eliot

Used as a noun, *the betrothed* can refer to a single such person, a couple, or multiple people.

---

In terms of commonality, [Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=26&content=the%20postulants%2Cthe%20betrothed%2Cthe%20espoused%2Cthe%20affianced&smoothing=3&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20postulants%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20betrothed%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20espoused%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20affianced%3B%2Cc0) shows that *the betrothed* is more common than *the espoused*, *the affianced*, or *the postulants* (and note that *espouse* also has the second sense of supporting a cause, meaning its *engaged* sense is even less common):

[image: the betrothed, espoused, affianced, and postulants]

---

Although *the betrothed* is arguably the most common and least esoteric of possible phrases with an article and a noun, I'd say it can't be as natural as just using *the bride and groom* in the first place (or *the brides* or *the grooms* in the case of same-sex marriages), or something like *the happy couple* where the context is known:

[image: the betrothed, espoused, affianced, postulants, bride and groom, and happy couple]

Answer (score 2):

You can say "the bridal couple."

Ex. The bridal couple and their attendants all wear yellow ribbons today in remembrance of the groom's father.

Answer (score 0):

If they're married, you could call them ***newlyweds***.

> **Newlywed (noun):** Someone who has recently married.
>
> Example: The hotel has a special discount rate for newlyweds.
> [[Cambridge English dictionary]](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/newlywed)

If they're not married yet, you could use ***affianced***.

> **Affianced (adj):** [literary]
> Engaged to be married.
>
> Example: An affianced couple.
> [[Lexico]](https://www.lexico.com/definition/affianced)